# WordPress Sage: how to fire JS on specific single or archive CPT pages?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In WordPress Sage's main.js we can run page-specific JS:

```
var Sage = {
  // All pages
  'common': {
    init: function() {
      // JavaScript to be fired on all pages
    },
    finalize: function() {
      // JavaScript to be fired on all pages, after page specific JS is fired
    }
  },
  // Home page
  'home': {
    init: function() {
      // JavaScript to be fired on the home page
    },
    finalize: function() {
      // JavaScript to be fired on the home page, after the init JS
    }
  },
  // About us page, note the change from about-us to about_us.
  'about_us': {
    init: function() {
      // JavaScript to be fired on the about us page
    }
  }
};
```

But how to run JS on specific single or archive CPT pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the classname on the body of the page/post/archive you want the JS to fire on and use one of those. For example if you had custom post type called 'work' the work archive body element would have a class of `post-type-archive-work`. Which you could use to fire your specific JS like so:

```
  // Note the change from about-us to about_us.
  'post_type_archive_work': {
    init: function() {
      // JavaScript to be fired on the 'work' archive
    }
  }
```

For more info check out [Paul Irish's post](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/)

Comment: I have a CPT called 'teams' and inside my body class I only see 'teams-template-default single single-teams' in the list of classes. 'post_type_single_teams' does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Josh Ellis's answer is correct, but a bit clarifications.
Class Router has the method:

```
/**
* Fire Router events
* @param {string} route DOM-based route derived from body classes (`<body class="...">`)
* @param {string} [event] Events on the route. By default, `init` and `finalize` events are called.
* @param {string} [arg] Any custom argument to be passed to the event.
*/
fire(route, event = 'init', arg) {
  const fire = route !== '' && this.routes[route] && typeof this.routes[route][event] === 'function';
  if (fire) {
    this.routes[route][event](arg);
  }
}
```

Use any class from the body. For example: 'teams-template-default single single-teams' => 'single_teams' or 'singleTeams' for Sage 9.